# Consume Web API in XML format (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin.forms

Web API returns result in XML format. I want to consume that web api and store the result in Picker. Here is the code:

**XAML.cs**

```
            Uri geturi = new Uri(URL);   
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await client.GetAsync(geturi);
         //string response = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //Xml Parsing  
            List<AClass> obj = new List<AClass>(); 
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("row")) //see XML
            {
                AClass dis = new AClass();
                dis.name = item.Element("name").Value.ToString(); //see XML
                obj.Add(dis);
            }
            //Binding listview with server response  
            picker.ItemsSource = obj;
```

**XML**

```
<row>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>A</name>
</row>
<row>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>B</name>
</row>
```

Error: 
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

I have referred http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2017/04/xamarinforms-consuming-rest-webserivce.html link

Comment: that's not a valid XML document.  XML should have a single root node

Comment: I can see the result in POSTMAN software.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything.  Your server is not returning valid XML, and XDocument is throwing an error when it tries to parse it.

Comment: Ok. Assuming it is an invalid XML, is the logic in XAML.cs file correct? Can I convert xml to json and then deserialize json?